# Am I able to change UI controls for the to-be-presented view controller in the prepareForSegue method

Tags: ios, user-interface, segue

Am I able to change UI controls for the to-be-presented view controller in the `prepareForSegue` method? Is it allowed and guaranteed to work? For example, I want to change the text of `UILabel`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storyboards make it easy to pass data from one scene to another using the prepareForSegue method, but you have not access to IBOutlet yet because it is called before viewDidLoad of the destination view controller.

You can do it this way:

1) In (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender, set a value for a NSString property, e.g.

```
[segue.destinationViewController setTextForLabel:@"This is a label text"];
```

2) in the destination view controller, you can set this property to the UILabel, for example in **viewWillAppear** or **viewDidLoad**:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.myLabel.text = self.textForLabel;
}
```

Comment: So I couldn't update `@IBOutlet` directly, only properties, am I right? Is there any reference to the documentation about this?

Comment: @FrozenHeart you are right. From Apple documentation: "Instead, view controllers are either instantiated by the storyboard either automatically by iOS when **a segue is triggered** or programmatically when your app calls the storyboard object’s instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: method. " [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html)

Comment: In other words, destination view controller is instantiated from a segue, and IBOutlet objects are instantiated when the view controller is initialized. Note that at build time the storyboard files are compiled into nib file, so the behavior is similar regarding the IBOutlet life cycle. See "The Nib Object Life Cycle"  [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html)

Comment: It's unclear for me from your answer that I shouldn't update any `@IBOutlet` in the `prepareForSegue` method. You said that "destination view controller is instantiated from a segue, and IBOutlet objects are instantiated when the view controller is initialized", so I think that I can do it because it's already initialized

Comment: Before a segue executes, the system gives the view controller involved a chance to prepare by calling prepareForSegue. The Segue is executed soon after. It is called **prepare** for this reason.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks a lot. Where can I read more about it, except "The Nib Object Life Cycle"?

Comment: You're welcome @FrozenHeart. The underlying reason is the same one that prevent you from access UI elements within the view controller -init methods.
An IBOutlet is initialized with the appropriate references at some point during the execution of the program [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Outlets/Outlets.html)

Comment: Again, an IBOutlet is connected only after loadview is called; but, the view controller call this method when its view is requested (e.g. when it needs to be shown) but is currently nil [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView)
And I think it should be what happens by the method's segue -perform, executed just after prepareForSegue.

Answer (score 0):

DestinationViewControllerclassname *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.labelname = the value you want to set(for e.g a string object);
Please note that labelname is a property of the view controller to be presented.

I am attaching my code for your reference below.

```
#import "NISViewController.h"
#import "NISCustomCell.h"
#import "NISRecipeDetailsViewController.h"
@interface NISViewController ()

@end

@implementation NISViewController
{
    NSArray *recipes;
    NSArray *images;
    NSArray *preptime;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"recipe" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];


    recipes =  [dic objectForKey:@"Name"];
    images  =  [dic objectForKey:@"Image"];
    preptime = [dic objectForKey:@"Time"];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [recipes count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

  NISCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner: self options: nil ];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green_tea"]];
        bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgView;


    }

    cell.thumb.image = [UIImage imageNamed : [images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.name.text = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.time.text = [preptime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mysegue" sender:self];
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mysegue"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NISRecipeDetailsViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.recipeName = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: So I couldn't update `@IBOutlet` directly, only properties, am I right? Is there any reference to the documentation about this?